# Calculate highest ratio

Tags: r, probability

I'm trying to find highest ration for column with given value.
Let's assume my data is like:

```
      Job          company
   =========================
    accountant     Bank
    accountant     Insurance Co
    Manager        Bank
    Manager        Bank
    accountant     Insurance Co
```

How to use group by if I want to find the highest ratio of accountant to manger with given company like Bank for example?

I'm trying something like this but not working,

```
MyData %>%
  count( MyData$Job,MyData$company) %>%
  group_by(MyData$Job) %>%
  mutate(prop = MyData$Job[accountant] / sum(MyData$Job[accountant])) %>%
  spread(key = company[bank], value = prop)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count()` is a wrapper for `group_by()` + `tally()` + `ungroup()`. Otherwise, based on your question, it doesn't sound as though you need `group_by()` again.

Also, you can refer to the variable names directly here, without the `$` symbol.

**Sample data**:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(
  Job = sample(c("Acct", "Manager"), size = 50, replace = TRUE),
  Company = sample(c("Bank", "Insurance"), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
)

> head(mydata)
      Job   Company
1    Acct      Bank
2    Acct Insurance
3 Manager      Bank
4 Manager      Bank
5    Acct      Bank
6 Manager      Bank
```

**Code**:

`count()` tallies the number for each job, within each company:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  count(Job, Company)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Job     Company       n
  <fctr>  <fctr>    <int>
1 Acct    Bank         17
2 Acct    Insurance     6
3 Manager Bank         12
4 Manager Insurance    15
```

`spread()` rearranges the dataframe such that each job is in its own column. In this case, each company is left in its own row:

```
library(tidyr)

mydata %>%
  count(Job, Company) %>%
  spread(Job, n)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Company    Acct Manager
* <fctr>    <int>   <int>
1 Bank         17      12
2 Insurance     6      15
```

If you want to calculate ratio of Accountant / Manager, you can do so directly:

```
mydata %>%
  count(Job, Company) %>%
  spread(Job, n) %>%
  mutate(p = Acct / Manager) %>%
  arrange(desc(p))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Company    Acct Manager     p
  <fctr>    <int>   <int> <dbl>
1 Bank         17      12 1.42 
2 Insurance     6      15 0.400
```

Comment: I get an error :Error in spread(., Job, n) : could not find function "spread" even though I installed tidyr package and dplyr !! any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, did you load the tidyr package after installing it? Alternatively, try `tidyr::spread(...)` instead of `spread(...)` to reference it directly.